# Crystal Reports - MS Access to SQL Server Migration

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

My project is created on the following specifications :

- Windows 7 (32 Bit).
- Visual Studio 2010.
- Windows Form VB.NET application.
- Microsoft Access 2007 as backend.
- Using Crystal Reports as reporting tool (version for Visual Studio 2010)

Due to storage size limitation of database, I have divided all tables into five databases.

My problem is with reporting tool, I am having multiple databases i.e five MS Access databases.
Therefore I am not able to use queries and therefore I am not able to use DataSets.

I only pass some parameters to report and heavily dependent on those for record selection in the reports relies on multiple databases.

Now, I want to migrate my application's backend to Microsoft SQL Server.

I am worrying If I need to create a bunch of reports once more in the conditions where I am not able to use Datasets.

Kindly suggest the easiest method to migrate all my Crystal Reports to a SQL Server database considering situations stated above.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you intend to combine your five databases into a single SQL Server database?

Comment: How are the tables divided into the five databases?  Do you have the same table in more than one database?

Comment: Yes. I intended to combine five databases into a single SQL Server database. By dividing I mean first I was having a single database then after couple of tables transferred to other databases. There are no same tables.

Comment: So you will have a single SQL Server database where before you used 5 Access databases.  I assume your table names will be the same.  Will anything else about the environment change?

Comment: everything as stated. I dont need help for transferring data, that i can do very well, i only need help regarding this with crystal reports.